# How to wrap multiple dll in a single dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging .net managed dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156321/merging-net-managed-dlls)

I create a test project in which I referenced a dll from some other project. When I build my test project, I see different dll for test project and the referenced dll. I want to wrap both dll's in a single dll.

How can I do it.

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by merging them?

Comment: In one of my project I am referring about 15 dlls. So I would Like to have a single dll for final product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at ILMerge:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx

With ILMerge you can merge a bunch of assemblies by running the command like:

ilmerge /out:MergedAssembly.dll ProjectAssembly1.dll ProjectAssembly2.dll ProjectAssembly3.dll

This will merge 3 assemblies into a single one.

Comment: Also, here is an article about it by By Scott Hanselman. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx

Comment: Beware however that this approach doesn't work for mixed-mode DLLs.

Comment: @Hps Oh nice, not seen that one, will be handy.

Comment: The command is creating a dll file but the size is 0KB?