# Can I merge 3rd party dlls into my project dll?

Tags: asp.net

I want to deploy my web application project as single dll. my question is that can I merge 3rd party dlls into my project dll in asp.net web application project?

Comment: [How to: Set the Copy Local Property of a Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap multiple dll in a single dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416632/how-to-wrap-multiple-dll-in-a-single-dll)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IL Merge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET
>   assemblies into a single assembly. It is freely available for use from
>   the Tools & Utilities page at the Microsoft .NET Framework Developer
>   Center.