# Bundling assemblies (DLLs) into one assembly for other's to reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, build

**Environment**: `Visual Studio 2013`, `C#`, `ASP.NET MVC`

**Question**: For the projects that I create in Visual Studio that use C#, I would like to give others one compiled DLL as opposed to them having to add any extra DLL references themselves.

**Example**:
I have a project that is used for web services:

```
MyProjectWebServices.dll <-- this is what I would just like to hand out
Some3rdParty.dll
Another.dll
SomethingElse.dll
```

So, for the above 4 libraries that other projects need to reference as well since my original distributable library (`MyProjectWebServices.dll`) references them, is there a way to bundle the bottom 3 into just the first one?

Comment: Have you looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416632/how-to-wrap-multiple-dll-in-a-single-dll

Comment: @ShaneHaw - That's it! https://github.com/Fody/Costura

Comment: Do not use costura for this. Use ilmerge instead

Comment: @Simon - care to explain as to the reason?

Comment: because costura is designed for exes and not dll. you will have unintended side effects if you use it for dlls