# Embed an library into my application and make it use that library

Tags: c#, mysql, embedded-resource

I want my executable to be the only thing needed for my program to work, but its dependant of a library, more specifically MySql.Data.dll. How can i incorporate this library into my executeable?

I've dragged the DLL into my project explorer. Furthermore i have selected it afterwards and set its `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`

However i still face a FileNotFound exception when i in my application try to open up a new window:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in    PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

EDIT:

Is this different from when using WinForms? I have been doing this earlier, with a WinForms application where i used the ioniczip and a json library, that i included as a Embedded ressource. This way i didnt need to include the two DLL files with the application.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2156321/232175 Generally speaking, you might want to be careful as the terms and conditions of the library might forbid doing that. By setting the Build Action, you only include the DLL content in your executable, but that doesn't allow .NET to use it. "Embedded Resource" should be used for including images, fonts etc. your application uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution. Add the DLL file as a ressource to the project and then i add this to App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string dllName = args.Name.Contains(',') ? args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) : args.Name.Replace(".dll", "");
    dllName = dllName.Replace(".", "_");
    if (dllName.EndsWith("_resources")) 
        return null;
    System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(GetType().Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])rm.GetObject(dllName);
    return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);
}
```

This did the trick for me it seems. I found it in an older project i had where i needed the same thing (simply forgot about it)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to copy all the dependencies to a folder specified in your PATH environment variable or put them at the same folder of your executable. You may find this article helpful [Search Path Used by Windows to Locate a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx)

If you want to bundle dlls, you may check out "ILMerge".

As for general errors like 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' or 'System.IO.BadImageException', you can try to use "Dependency Walker" to figure out what dlls are missing.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use Embedded Resource to distribute a library. You need somethig like ILMerge. 
See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx